# Any idea why a Spinner component fails in some smartphones and loads properly in others?

Tags: android, list, spinner

This is one of the weirdest errors I have encountered while working with android apps.  I have a code section that pulls from an array dynamically to populate the Spinner component in my app.  The Spinner is populated without any problems when run on my Oukitel K10 smartphone running android 7.0 but fails to populate on my Tecno Camon 15, which is a very recent smartphone with good RAM and processing power.

I sincerely hope someone has had a similar experience so they can share how best to resolve this problem.

What can possibly be the reason for this unusual behavior of the Spinner component on different Smartphones?

Thank you in advance.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/appback2"

    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    tools:context=".payElectActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#74CDBBD7"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pageHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pay Electricity Bill"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:background="#9C27B0"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="30dp" />


        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/electspinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
            android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/meterno"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:hint="Enter Meter No."
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/verifynow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:textColor="@color/colorYellow2"
            android:background="@drawable/action_button2"
            android:text="Do Customer Verification" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"

            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customerinfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"


                android:text="..."
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"

                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="18dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/mtrspinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:popupTheme="@android:style/ThemeOverlay.Material.Light"
            android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phonenumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:hint="Recipient's Phone"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#B9E5D1F1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/amount1000"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

                android:textColor="#080309"
                android:background="#8B716A72"
                android:text="1000"

                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/amount1500"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"


                android:textColor="#080309"
                android:background="#8BC3A48D"
                android:text="1500"

                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/amount2000"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

                android:textColor="#080309"
                android:background="#8B716A72"
                android:text="2000"

                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/amount3000"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"


                android:textColor="#080309"
                android:background="#8BC3A48D"
                android:text="3000"

                android:gravity="center"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/amount5000"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

                android:background="#8B716A72"
                android:textColor="#080309"

                android:text="5000"

                android:gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amounttopay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"

            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:hint="Enter Amount"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="#B9E5D1F1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/topupnow"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"

            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"

            android:textColor="#9C27B0"
            android:background="@drawable/action_button1"
            android:text="Do Recharge"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvIsConnected"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>>


</LinearLayout>
```

electspinner is the spinner component

Then I loaded the array by using this code section

```
electspinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.electspinner);

        //Get the list of products
         doDiscosArray();

        //Get the list of Networks

        adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(payElectActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,allNetworks);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        electspinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        electspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

below are the other code modules

```
 private void doDiscosArray() {

        String verifyURL = "http://mmgetreuutter.com/httpapi/power-lists?userid=0844356451&pass=305f988a5536ddsa81a2";


         result = "";

        if(netConn){
            //Instantiate new instance of our class
            HTTPAsyncTask getRequest = new HTTPAsyncTask();
           //Perform the doInBackground method, passing in our url
            try {
                //Get array list from jsonbinio
                result = getRequest.execute(verifyURL,"1").get();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


    }
```

The section performs the actual loading of the array

```
if( typeUrl.equals("1") || typeUrl.equals("51"))
                {
                   String responseVal="";

                   JSONArray nodesArray =null;


                    if (typeUrl.equals("51"))
                    nodesArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("alldiscos");
                     else  nodesArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("result");

                 

                   allNetworks.clear();

                    for (int i=0; i < nodesArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject itemArr = (JSONObject)nodesArray.get(i);

                         prodID = itemArr.getString("product_id");
                         discoName = itemArr.getString("name");

                         pathName = discoName+"~"+prodID;

                        allNetworks.add(pathName);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }

            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: Could you please add the code? Without nobody can help you.

Comment: I have added more codes.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It boiled down to just changing “http://” to “https://” in the original request.  Very sad because it was just a missing ‘s’ character, but fulfilling that I eventually resolved my most challenging error. It showed that the GET request I was making from my App to get the list was erratic since it would allow for a secured request with some smartphones but others can by-pass it.  It was an amazing learning experience.